# T-SQL IS NOT NULL vs NOT NULL performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, comparison

I have read a lot of not using negative operators like *NOT IN* and *NOT EXISTS* and how reversing your logic to positive operators, for example using *IN* instead *NOT IN* could lead to very good performance.

Anyway, I have a view with a lot of CASE WHEN operators and checking some conditions. I  have wondered (still I have been able to find any article, question or example specific for this) will be a performance difference in using *IS NOT NULL* and *IS NULL*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both can be carried out as an index seek.

One of them seeking into the beginning of the index reading all the rows with `NULL` then stopping when it encounters the first `NOT NULL` and the other one seeking into the first `NOT NULL` value then reading the entire rest of the index.

Unless the index is covering however a seek may not be used in either case as it comes down to selectivity. If you have many `NULL` values so `NOT NULL` is highly selective you might want to consider creating a filtered index on that column [as per the example here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I have found the "filterer" index very useful.